# Making sense of sinogram of perspex block in air

Tags: optics, visible-light, refraction

I'm confused trying to visualize what happened exactly during this experiment:

Setup with a laser and a photo diode on the opposite side. 
A perspex block (2x2cm) in between.
Take 200 measurements over 10 cm (to get 0.5 mm pixels)
After this the block will rotate x degrees (x = 180/157 , 157 the number of projections)
And take 200 measurements again. Repeat for all 157 angles.

The sinogram obtained from this (each column is 1 scan at angle x): 
(intensity in sinogram represents the integration of attenuation values of the object, so colder color means more light going through)
[image: sinogram of perspex block]

The iradon reconstruction:
[image: reconstruction of the object from projection data using iradon]
I understand the reconstruction is bad because of refraction (refractive index of the block is 1.49 and measured in air). And at certain angles even total internal reflection will occur. And that this can be solved mostly with measuring in a fluid like glycerol.

But I can't explain this:

1) why is the intensity of the measured light higher through the perspex, than outside of it? The sinogram value outside the block is ~1, the dark blue inside is ~0,85.
2) what exactly causes the black 'triangles', and the shape in general, in the reconstruction?

Thank you!